# Presto - pivot table

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, presto

Hi I have a table like this:

```
Session id  Property
1           Radar
2           Bullet
1           Bullet
3           Radar
2           Price
```

I want to convert it into like this:

```
Radar   Bullet   Price
  1       1
          2        2
  3
```

Comment: What's the expected result if someone later inserts the row (1, Apple)?

Comment: A new column with name 'Apple' and only one value of 1 in the first row

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: What did you try? Pls, post your code.

Comment: Answer from GMB worked

Comment: `select 
    case when max(case when property = 'Radar'  then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then session_id end as radar,
    case when max(case when property = 'Bullet' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then session_id end as bullet,
    case when max(case when property = 'Price'  then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then session_id end as price 
from mytable
group by session_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed list of properties, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select session_id,
    max(case when property = 'Radar'  then 1 else 0 end) as radar,
    max(case when property = 'Bullet' then 1 else 0 end) as bullet,
    max(case when property = 'Price'  then 1 else 0 end) as price
from mytable
group by session_id
```

This puts the session id in the first column and `0`/`1` values in each column, depending on whether the given session owns the given property.

To generate the exact output you showed (which might be a little less helpful than the above), you would do:

```
select 
    case when max(case when property = 'Radar'  then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then session_id end as radar,
    case when max(case when property = 'Bullet' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then session_id end as bullet,
    case when max(case when property = 'Price'  then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then session_id end as price 
from mytable
group by session_id
```